# Replace condition with mode in Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I need a pandas code for the following data.Here I need a condition for replace the value.if product name is A,price needs to be the mode value of A and replace all the value.At the end The value of A is 5 in every row.

| Product | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 6 |
| A | 7 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| A | Nan |
| c | 4 |
| D | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary, `keys` being the values from Product column and `values` will be their respective  `mode` price, and then `map` it back to your dataframe based on your Product column:

```
df.assign(Price=df['Product'].map(
    df.groupby(['Product'])['Price'].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_dict()))
```

prints:

```
   Product  Price
0        A      5
1        A      5
2        A      5
3        B      8
4        B      8
5        B      8
6        A      5
7        A      5
8        A      5
9        c      4
10       D      3
```

Comment: How to add value to missing data here here. I changed the data. If there is a Nan value i need to fill that too.

Comment: The answer provided will still work :) Feel free to test it

Comment: I need to specify A. Like if product name is A, then need to replace all the value using mode.Can you help me?

Comment: I think I can. I just need you to explain your problem thoroughly please. Do you want to replace only the Values of A with their mode?

Comment: Yes.only needs to replace the value of A

Comment: So then the question is that you want to replace all the values of A, to be it's mode. Right? So everything should be 5 for A, and for the other Products it should be left intact.

Comment: yes..exactly...i will change the question.

Comment: ```df['Price'] = np.where(
    df['Product'].eq('A'),df[df['Product']=='A']['Price'].mode()[0],df['Price'])``` try this?